# How to remove UIWebView code in cordova-plugin-firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

After the UIWebView deprecation api warning from the apple team, the cordova team researched and released their cordova-ios@5.1.0 which disables the UIWebView at compile time.However after adding the cordova-plugin-firebase plugin I still receive the warning mail from the apple team. I am currently working on ionic3 hybrid ionic-cordova app.Any kind of inputs will be surely helpful.Or do I have to wait for the plugin maintainers to update their code.

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of Firebase have removed `UIWebView` from [all libraries except AdMob](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3862).

So yes, the plugin maintainers to need to update.

Comment: Is there a way we can check for the version of the firebase SDK's used in a plugin. If there is, how can we update them within a project level?